# curl settings for ebay GetOrders api

Tags: php, curl, ebay-api

I want to fetch orders from my ebay seller account.
I have integrated successfully on my local but when i hosted it to live then it gives error like :

> Warning: curl_exec() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/GetOrders/get-common/eBaySession.php on line 74
>       Error sending request

when i see my phpinfo() it gives curl enabled. and I'm sure it's enabled because i'm using one another api with curl in my site as well.

help me please to get out from this.
Thanks

Comment: *"Warning: curl_exec() has been disabled"*. Read the error message. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-lighttpd-phpini-disable-functions/

Answer (score 1):

The module might be activated, but it could be in the disabled list. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16421940/6224185),

> There is a **php.ini directive called disable_functions**. Functions added to this list will be disabled by PHP and when you try to execute those functions, you get this error. As mentioned, in all probability your hosting provider has added exec to the disabled list.

Comment: disable_functions are empty.
and in the same system i wrote code like
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Basic '.  base64_encode('aaaaaa:aaaa')));
    $status_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
    $result = curl_exec ($curl);
This executes well but ebay call gives an error.

Comment: Are you running in safe mode?

Comment: it gives phpinfo() disabled also for security reason

Comment: What is the exact location of your php.ini (the one you said where disable_functions was empty)? Does it match with the location the following command returns: "php --ini" ? Does it return additional php.ini locations? Note: PHP can use more than one or two additional php.ini files.

Answer (score 0):

look your `php.ini`  file if `curl_exec` is listed inside `disable_functions`. if yes, remove it.

ex.

```
$ locate php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
/usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-development
/usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-production
/usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-production.cli
$ cat /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini  | grep disable_functions
disable_functions = pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,\
pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wifcontinued,pcntl_wexitstatus,\
pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,\
pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,\ pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,
```

Comment: disable_functions are empty.

Comment: what is output of `locate php.ini`?

Comment: php.ini is located at project root

Comment: is it your local machine or a hosting service?

Comment: it's hosting service

Comment: that's the reason. better change your service provider or ask them if they have some plans which gives you full command on system. otherwise use some other php http clients, such as `guzzle`. by the way, guzzle is easy to use.